# How do I make a day/night automatic double door?

Tags: minecraft-redstone, minecraft-legacy-console

How do I make a double door which opens and closes depending on whether it's day or night?

Comment: maybe it'll be worth to do some research first and explain the problems you are having. some basic research would lead you to the [daylight sensor](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Daylight_sensor) and on that page tutorials for a night time detector

Comment: some things you might want to look into first are [Daylight Sensors](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Daylight_Sensor), [Redstone circuits](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Redstone_circuit), (specifically the "Not Gate"). Have go with this stuff first - It's very straight forward, and then if you have issues with getting that working, we'd be glad to help :)

Comment: This is one of the most basic redstone designs there is, except for a few problems with the double door instead of a single door (and if that's your problem, tell us). Have you tried anything? By "I suck at Redstone", do you mean you don't understand even the most basic concepts such as connecting a button to a door?

Comment: do you want it open during day or night? I need to know this, since it pretty much changes the whole design.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

This is what it should look like if you want it closed at night.

If you want it open at night, just remove the NOT gates (the restone torches on the blocks) and replace that with redstone, and Ta-Da! You have an automatic door powered by daylight :)

Comment: I want it open during the day and closed at night. Pikmin, I might go with the Pistons instead of the door, it looks lazy and half assed with the doors.


I did some experimenting and I figured it out

Sudoku, by I suck at red stone, I meant I get the basic concepts, but anything above a NOT gate completely befuddles me


Thank you all for the help though!